# Ansible: Include a file if it exists and do nothing if it doesn't

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a Jinja2 template in Ansible and I need to include some files conditionally.

Basically, I have a for loop that includes "subparts" that might or might not be present. The following sample demonstrates the basic code that would work if all tools actually had a 'pbr.j2' file, but it crashes because Ansible cannot find some of the files:

```
{% for tool in tools %}
   {% set template = 'tools/' + tool.name + '/pbr.j2' %}
   {% include template %}
{% endfor %}
```

I have also tried the `exists` and `is_file` filters, but I always get "false" even when the file exists. Here is a sample code of what I have tried:

```
{% for tool in tools %}
   {% set template = 'tools/' + tool.name + '/pbr.j2' %}
   {% if template|exists %}
      {% include template %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The result of this last sample is that no file gets included. If I replace `exists` with `is_file`, I get the same behavior.

What do I need to change to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use Ansible filters (`exists`, `is_file`)  in a Jinja2 template. This works for templates processed by Ansible templating engine, but not for templates processed by the `template` module.

Jinja2 does not have capability to check the existence of a file, so you need to move your logic to Ansible.

For example: create a `find` task to search for directories in `tools/`, and provide an intersection of `find`-results list with `tools` list to Jinja2.

Comment: I saw that the filters were supposed to be used in .yml files and I couldn't find any help referencing file testing in Jinja2 templates, but I figured that there probably was some easy way such as filters to accomplish what I want but that it just wasn't documented. I'll go with the task route instead and pass the list to the Jinja2 template. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 15):

I have found a solution to my problem: using `ignore missing` in the include directive.

In this case, I would use:

```
{% for tool in tools %}
   {% set template = 'tools/' + tool.name + '/pbr.j2' %}
   {% include template ignore missing %}
{% endfor %}
```

Ansible will ignore missing files and only the existing files from that loop will get included.